# Handle JDBC exception in BIRT API

Tags: scheduled-tasks, birt, job-scheduling

I have a scheduler job which is based on a standalone RunAndRenderTask. The report design connects to a remote mysql database to fetch data. The scheduler generates a PDF and emails the report as attachment to a set of people. This works as long as the database is available.

But when the database is unavailable, then I can see the error in the logs, but the RunAndRenderTask still generates a PDF report which is blank and useless, and this gets emailed by the scheduler. I need to be able to catch this exception and instead email another set of people who can fix the DB issue. I tried various things but couldn't figure out how to do it. 
In the code below, I expect the API to return an exception, and hence print "BirtException" or "Exception", but this code prints "Success" even when there is a JDBC exception.
Any help is appreciated.

Here's the code I have.

```
        IReportEngine engine = null;
    IRunAndRenderTask runAndRenderTask = null;

    try  {
        EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
        config.setEngineHome("birt-runtime-4_4_0/RuntimeEngine");
        Platform.startup(config);
        IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
                .createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
        engine = factory.createReportEngine(config);

        IReportRunnable reportRunnable = engine.openReportDesign(DATA_PATH + "sample.rptdesign");
        runAndRenderTask = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(reportRunnable);

        PDFRenderOption option = new PDFRenderOption();
        option.setOutputFileName(DATA_PATH + "output.pdf");
        option.setOutputFormat("pdf");

        runAndRenderTask.setRenderOption(option);
        runAndRenderTask.run();
        System.out.println("Success!");
    } catch (BirtException e) {
        System.out.println("BirtException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (runAndRenderTask != null) {
            runAndRenderTask.close();
        }

        if (engine != null) {
            engine.destroy();               
        }
        Platform.shutdown();
        RegistryProviderFactory.releaseDefault();
    }
```

This is the exception stacktrace, which never gets propagated back by RunAndRenderTask.run()

```
    INFO: Loaded JDBC driver class in class path: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    Jun 26, 2014 9:26:43 PM org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager openConnection
    SEVERE: Unable to open connection.
    org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: There is an error in get connection, Communications link failure

     The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server..
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.doConnect(JDBCDriverManager.java:336)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.getConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:235)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.connectByUrl(Connection.java:252)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Connection.open(Connection.java:162)
at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaConnection.open(OdaConnection.java:250)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:165)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.newConnection(DataSource.java:224)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSource.open(DataSource.java:212)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataSourceRuntime.openOdiDataSource(DataSourceRuntime.java:217)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.openDataSource(QueryExecutor.java:435)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.prepareExecution(QueryExecutor.java:322)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.doPrepare(PreparedQuery.java:463)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.produceQueryResults(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:190)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.execute(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:178)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.execute(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:178)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.execute(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:637)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:152)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:275)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedGenerateExecutor.executeQueries(ExtendedGenerateExecutor.java:205)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedGenerateExecutor.execute(ExtendedGenerateExecutor.java:65)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExtendedItemExecutor.execute(ExtendedItemExecutor.java:62)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:181)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
at test.ReportTester.test(ReportTester.java:50)
at test.ReportTester.main(ReportTester.java:19)
```

Comment: You mentioned scheduled job. What platform for job/task scheduling you use in this case?

Comment: The schedule job is pretty trivial implementation using [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

Comment: It's naive, but, your catch block is empty. This is not your running code?

Comment: @Miki, thanks for following up. Yes, this is just the relevant code snippet. All I do is throw new RuntimeException(e) in the catch(Exception e) block, and let the caller handle it. But JDBC exception doesn't get caught here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to catching `BirtException`, you should be aware that the way BIRT handles Javascript errors is - by default - browser-like. That is, BIRT tries to continue generating the report.

There are different ways to handle this for production-quality code (where `task` is a RunAndRenderTask or RunTask or RenderTask):

- Use `task.setErrorHandlingOption(CANCEL_ON_ERROR)` (see  [BIRT docs](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc.isv%2Fengine%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fbirt%2Freport%2Fengine%2Fapi%2FIEngineTask.html)). Personally, I have never tried this.
- After `task.run(...)`, but before `task.close()`, call `task.getErrors()`. If this list is not empty, your code should output these messages and throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score -1):

You need to add catch block that catches **EngineException**, not JDBC exception.

You can find javadocs [at link](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.birt.doc.isv%2Fengine%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fbirt%2Freport%2Fengine%2Fapi%2FIRunAndRenderTask.html).

Comment: I edited to add more clarity about exception handling. EngineException actually is a subclass of BirtException, which in turn is subclassed from Exception. So, if run was throwing back EngineException, it'd have been caught. But looks like the exception is not propagated back.

Comment: you are using version 4.4, try using older version. if it still fails, report bug to  or wait other answers here. ;)

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I've tried the older versions too, and the behavior is the same. Have posted this on [BIRT community](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/783270/1388547/#msg_1388547), will also report a bug.